# why does the compillation of a program yield a command not found error?

Tags: c, linux

I am currently using a program called `Triangle` which you can find more about in [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/triangle.html)

From such website, you can download a makefile, a `triangle.c` ,a `tricall.c` , `showme.c` (may be run in X only), A.poly, a readme file and a `triangle.h`.

I think I have managed to compile a C program called triangle successfully on linux (after writing in the terminal `cc -O -o triangle triangle.c -lm` I am getting no errors).
However, if after this I write `triangle -h` or simply `triangle`, I get the error:

```
triangle: command not found
```

According to the author of the code I should be able to get the instructions after writing the first of the two aforementioned commands but I just get that error.

Do you know what may be wrong? Should not the linux terminal recognize triangle or at least show debugging errors from the `triangle.h` code?

If you think it may have something to do with the makefile I can reproduce it again(it is short).
Thanks so much.

Comment: Try `./triangle`. In linux you need to give the path of the file unless the path is in the `PATH` environment variable. The current directory is typically not in `PATH`.

Comment: The reason `.` is not included in the `PATH` by default is so you can't "hijack" someone's shell, as in if you had a hostile `ls` binary in your directory then an admin doing `ls` could inadvertently run your program, not `/bin/ls`. As such you need to say "I mean run the thing right here".